# Need simple regex (regular expression) for dynamic expression

Tags: regex, expression, regular-language

I need a regex to replace this text:

```
("{scriptid}_*0123_00000000_ABC-Description*");
```

With this text:

```
("{scriptid}_*0123_00000000_ABC-Description*"));
```

Or in other words: *I have to add a second closing brace.

Explanation:

```
("{scriptid}_*0123_00000000_ABC-Description*");

("{scriptid}_4-digits_8-alphanumeric_X-alphanumeric-description");
```

I tried some expressions but it doesn't really work.

Could some one please help me?

Comment: How about `s/;/);/`?

Comment: The regex doesn't work, it seems to be invalid. Please consider almost every line in the code ends with: ....");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic regex that matches all the lines ending with `');'` (match also if there are trailing spaces) can be this:

```
s/\);\s*$/\)\);/
```

Test online [here](https://regex101.com/r/bT4aL1/1).

**UPDATE**: generic regex that adds a closing parenthesis, matches only lines starting with `lr_start_transaction`:

```
s/^\s*(lr_start_transaction.*\))\s*;\s*$/\1\);/
```

Test online [here](https://regex101.com/r/bT4aL1/3).

Anyway, if we are not talking about generic regex you have to also specify the language you are coding with (cause each regex engine is thinly different).

Consider also to include some lines that does not have to match.

Comment: @Troste: which are the lines you do not want to match? Can you paste more of your data online? (you can modify directly the link with the regex or use a paste online service).

Comment: Hi, I tried to use your expression s/\);\s*$/\)\);/ with notepad++ but it doesn't work: no results. The expression \);\s*$ is working but unfortunaltly for every line that ends with ...");  I need a expression just for the specific text. Please consider almost every line in the code ends with: ....");   If it helps, I can show u a bigger part of the script/code

Comment: I updated the code https://regex101.com/r/bT4aL1/2    I need a second closing brace just at the end of the line beginning with "lr_start_transaction..."

Comment: @Troste: i've updated the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/bT4aL1/3) to match your request. For fairness update the question too.

Comment: @Troste: in my version of Notepad++ (the splitted version, as on regex101) [work correctly](http://pasteboard.co/1uInkuHr.png)

Comment: Could you please update the code in the online editor?

Comment: @Troste: i've updated the answer, anyway the regex101 version of the last version is [here](https://regex101.com/r/bT4aL1/3)

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. I added 2 "/r" in the subtitution expression (\r\1\);\r) and now the replacement works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your initial string, you can select it with this:

```
/(\("\{scriptid\}_[0-9]{4}_[a-z0-9]{8}_[-a-z0-9]+"\));$/i
```

The `$` matches the end of the line, and the `i` flag is for **case-insensitive**.

You can then replace with `$1);` (To simplify the replacement, I left the `;` out of the capture group in the match.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation but @GsusRecovery solution is working fine for me.